# Auto or cross correlation for synchronisation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, continuous-signals

I have multiples records of  a motor sound, I would like to synchronize them first and then  calculate their spectrogram. My question is how can I use the autocorrelation or the crosscorrelation to synchronize them? I want to make sure that the only difference I see in the spectrogram is related to the frequency, not to the start position of the motor or the records.

I know to calculate the auto and cross correlation in MATLAB but I don't understand how to use them for synchronization purpose.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly it is a very simple task. Here is the example for shifted sinusoid:

```
t = linspace(0,6*pi,1000); % time vector for sinusoid
s = [zeros(1,100), sin(2*pi*t), zeros(1,100)];  % original signal
shift = 30; % we are shifting our sinusoid 30 bins to the right
ss = [zeros(1, shift) s(1:end-shift)]; % signal shifted
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(s); hold on;
plot(ss, 'r')

[c, lags] = xcorr(ss, s); % get the cross-correlation together with lags
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(lags, c)

pred_shift = lags(c==max(c)); % calculated the shift from maximum value of cross-correlation
```

The output is: `30` and you can use it to shift back the signal `ss`. In your case of engine signals it will be analogous.

Comment: thanks for replying, but how can I put the shift the ss signal back ?

Comment: @Engine: Sorry for not responding - I am in travel. If you have any more queries then feel free to ask.